# ollydbg - how to keep debugged program window open

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

Any way to keep debugged program window open while stepping the code in ollydbg? The program displays buttons in a loop in a dialog box. But its window stays minimized so I can't observe what effect each command has on visual display.

source: https://legend.octopuslabs.io/sample-page.html (tutorial 16A)

Comment: I'm afraid it is just "stuck" since you are debugging it.

Comment: @Geno Chen That's what I thought, but the author posts "screenshots" of buttons being created in loop iterations and it creates an impression that it somehow should be possible; the thumbnail of the window is still available so the information is there, but how do I access it?

Comment: In my remember, you can just keep it there, don't let OlldDbg maximize to hover over this window, will let you can see it.

Comment: @Geno Chen Thanks, that actually solves it. It should be marked as accepted answer but since it's a comment it doesn't seem possible. Any moderator here?

Comment: I wrote an (may be more detailed and contain some error) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are debugging this program, the program will be "stuck" before GUI components initialized and enter the main loop of GUI thread. You can just keep all window away of "hovering" the program's window, for example **don't** maximize your OllyDbg window.